# Error in accessing tweets --> "Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming

I have developer access and was attempting to execute Twitter streaming using Spark Scala but I faced the following problem:

```
Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true
Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to give V2 credentials. hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: may I know how can I do that in Flume? do I need to change the conf file?